# Push all inputs ids and values into json array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an error when I run this code this way...

```
var action = $("#action_button").html();
var results = [];
    
$('#main_form input').each(function(){
    results.push({
        this.id : this.value
        });
});

var json = JSON.stringify(results);
```

... but I don't get the results I want when I execute it this way...

```
var action = $("#action_button").html();
var results = [];
    
$('#main_form input').each(function(){
    results.push({
        id:this.id
        value: this.value
        });
});

var json = JSON.stringify(results);
```

**I want it to return:**

```
 {id: "22", first_name: "john", last_name: "smith"}
```

**It is currently returning:**

```
 {"id":"id","value":"22"},{"id":"first_name","value":"john"}, 
 {"id":"last_name","value":"smith"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.push()` is for array `[]`, for object `{}` use `object[key] = value`

```js
var results = {}; // <== object
$('#main_form input').each(function() {
  results[this.id] = this.value;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="main_form">

id: <input id="id" value="22" /><br>
name: <input id="first_name" value="john" /> <br> 
surname: <input id="last_name" value="smith" /><br>

</form>
```

Comment: @Spring   how can `results.push({[this.id]: this.value});` same with `results[this.id] = this.value;` ?

Comment: apologize havent noticed that , my answer clearly wasn't quite right thumbs ;)

Answer (score 1):

use the array `[val]` to create **dynamic computed property** (getting value as key ) as below:

also as @uingtea mentiend use for result object `{}` instead of array `[]`

```
$('#main_form input').each(function() {
   results[this.id]= this.value
});
```

```js
var $actionBtn = $("#action_button");
var results = {};

$actionBtn.on("click", function() {
  $('#main_form input').each(function() {
    results[this.id]= this.value
  });

  var json = JSON.stringify(results);
  console.log(json);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="main_form">

  id ----------> <input id="id" value="22" /><br> 
  name ------> <input id="first_name" value="john" /> <br>
  surname --> <input id="last_name" value="smith" /><br>

</form>


<button id="action_button"> generate</button>
```